# How to locate a tag by text in its child tag

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am new to Webelement and selenium, can anyone help me on how to locate element below , using text "Hotel Wahington":

```
<a class="hotel_name_link url" href="/hotel/nl/washington.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaFCIAQGYATG4ARjIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgS4Apyz__EFwAIB&amp;sid=1b691d9ad57ac7ee7c3d40dac2f7f488&amp;dest_id=-2140479&amp;dest_type=city&amp;group_adults=2&amp;group_children=0&amp;hapos=1&amp;hpos=1&amp;no_rooms=1&amp;sr_order=popularity&amp;srepoch=1581242789&amp;srpvid=87de4712b9a90095&amp;ucfs=1&amp;from=searchresults;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
  <span class="sr-hotel__name" data-et-click="    ">Hotel Washington</span>
  <span class="invisible_spoken">Opens in new window</span>
</a>
```

Adding the original link below :
https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaFCIAQGYATG4ARjIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgS4ApSSgPIFwAIB&sid=dcd3ff4c30abfd0bc264d5ae4a4c1d7a&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaFCIAQGYATG4ARjIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgS4ApSSgPIFwAIB%3Bsid%3Ddcd3ff4c30abfd0bc264d5ae4a4c1d7a%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&sr_autoscroll=1&ss=hotel+washington&is_ski_area=0&checkin_year=&checkin_month=&checkout_year=&checkout_month=&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1

Comment: You may want to learn about XPATH queries https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select anchor tag based on `text "Hotel Wahington"` use the following xpath.

Use following Xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='hotel_name_link url' and contains(.,'Hotel Washington')]").click()
```

Or following css selector.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.hotel_name_link.url[href*='/hotel/nl/washington']").click()
```

Or partial link text.

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Hotel Washington").click()
```

Comment: Seems like I still cannot locate this element , below is the links I used to locate the elements, could you help to take look on it ?

Comment: https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaFCIAQGYATG4ARjIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgS4AsiEgPIFwAIB&sid=3fe3ed17d977346dc4016787c46d67d9&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaFCIAQGYATG4ARjIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgS4AsiEgPIFwAIB%3Bsid%3D3fe3ed17d977346dc4016787c46d67d9%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&sr_autoscroll=1&ss=hotel+washington&is_ski_area=0&checkin_year=&checkin_month=&checkout_year=&checkout_month=&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1

Comment: One more question is , is "Xpath" the only way I can locate this element ? Can I locate it in other ways , like by "link text" / "tag name" , etc ?

Comment: it works perfectly well , all 3 solutions. May I ask what kind of keywords I can google if i want to locate any webelement like you do - in different ways . Xpath/CSS ? is that what I need to learn ?

Comment: You can learn xpath from this link https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html and https://www.guru99.com/locators-in-selenium-ide.html

Answer (score 0):

Using `xpath` you can go to parent element with `..`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[.="Hotel Washington"]/..')
```

Or locate an element which has specific text

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[span[.="Hotel Washington"]]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
xPath = //*[contains(@text(),'Hotel Wahington')]
```

**OR**

```
//a[@class='hotel_name_link url']//*[contains(@text(),'Hotel Wahington')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tryout this xpath:
//span[text()='Hotel Washington']/parent::a

Also note that the method "find_element_by_xpath()" in the answers is from version 4 of Selenium which is still in Alpha testing phase. You will be most likely using Selenium version 3. The valid code for version 3 would be:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Hotel Washington']/parent::a")),click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can locate an element using `text` only. You can try below solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Hotel Washington')]")))
element.click()
```